# Salesforce Field Service Lightning Refer Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Our requirement is to show asset details in Field Service Lightning application.  We have completed below steps so far,

1. We have created lightning component to show asset details.
2. This lightning component accepts Asset Id and then shows asset details. This is working fine in Salesforce1 and Lightning application.
3. We are trying to refer this lightning component application by using App extension from (Field Service Mobile Settings). App Extension details are as below,
   i.   Name: Asset Hierarchy
   ii.  Type: Lightning App
   iii. Launch Value: AssetLightningcompApp
   iv.  Scoped To Object: WorkOrder,Asset
   v.   Installation URL:
4. When we are clicking on Asset Hierarchy in FSL application it gives blank page.

Please help us to understand how to refer lightning component in Field service lightning application.

Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the bottom of page 110 here: http://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_field_service_implementation_guide.pdf

It states that you can pass values using the **Launch Value** section. It may be worth seeing if you can put a standard merge field in there and see if it work, example:

```
Lightning_App_Name?recordId={! WorkOrder.Id }
```

I am not too sure if that will, but it's worth a try :)